# Forward request headers - apollo federated gateway

Tags: node.js, express, apollo, apollo-federation

I'm using the following versions:

- "@apollo/gateway": "^2.1.3"
- "@apollo/server": "^4.0.0"
- "graphql": "^16.6.0"

I can't get a handle on the `req` object to extract the headers and forward them. The `buildService` code works to add headers to requests to downstream services, but the `context` on ApolloServer is consistently empty. I tried sync and async, request instead of req. I even tried grabbing them directly from `context.req.headers`, but that's null.

Anyone have any idea on how to accomplish this?

```js
const gateway = new ApolloGateway({
  supergraphSdl: new IntrospectAndCompose({
    subgraphs: [
      { name: "persons", url: process.env.PERSON_SERVER_URL },
    ],
  }),
  buildService({ url }) {
    return new RemoteGraphQLDataSource({
      url,
      willSendRequest: ({ request, context }) => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(context));
        // TRYING TO INJECT AUTH HEADERS HERE
      }
    });
  }
});

const app = express();
const httpServer = http.createServer(app);

const server = new ApolloServer({
  gateway,
  context: ({ req }) => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(req));
    // req IS NULL
  },
  plugins: [
    ApolloServerPluginLandingPageDisabled(),
    ApolloServerPluginDrainHttpServer({ httpServer })
  ]
});
await server.start();

const graphqlRoute = "/graphql";
app.use(
  graphqlRoute,
  bodyParser.json(),
  expressMiddleware(server),
);

await new Promise((resolve) => httpServer.listen(process.env.PORT, "0.0.0.0", resolve));
console.log(` Server ready at ${JSON.stringify(httpServer.address())}`);
```

For what it's worth, I asked [here](https://community.apollographql.com/t/federation-forward-headers-to-subgraphs/4917), as well. This feels like it should be a simple flag (especially for federation) to forward the Authorization header.

Answer (score 2):

you need to read headers from request in expressMiddleware, next save them in context and then they will be available in willSendRequest, try:

```
const gateway = new ApolloGateway({
  supergraphSdl: new IntrospectAndCompose({
    subgraphs: [
      { name: "persons", url: process.env.PERSON_SERVER_URL },
    ],
  }),
  buildService({ url }) {
    return new RemoteGraphQLDataSource({
      url,
      willSendRequest: ({ request, context }) => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(context));
        for (const [headerKey, headerValue] of Object.entries(context.headers)) {
          request.http?.headers.set(headerKey, headerValue);
        }
      }
    });
  }
});

const app = express();
const httpServer = http.createServer(app);

const server = new ApolloServer({
  gateway,
  plugins: [
    ApolloServerPluginLandingPageDisabled(),
    ApolloServerPluginDrainHttpServer({ httpServer })
  ]
});
await server.start();

const graphqlRoute = "/graphql";

async function context({ req }) {
  return {
    headers: req.headers,
  };
}

app.use(
  graphqlRoute,
  bodyParser.json(),
  expressMiddleware(server, {context: context}),
);

await new Promise((resolve) => httpServer.listen(process.env.PORT, "0.0.0.0", resolve));
console.log(` Server ready at ${JSON.stringify(httpServer.address())}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

in AS4, ApolloServer has an API that isn't specific to a framework, and the argument to the context function is framework-specific. a la

```js
app.use(
  graphqlRoute,
  cors(),
  bodyParser.json(),
  expressMiddleware(server, {
    context: async ({ req }) => ({
      token: req.headers.authorization
    }),
  }),
);
```